# iOS 9 unable to access camera from addressbookui/contactsui while adding a new contact

Tags: ios9, addressbookui

Since iOS 9 while adding a new contact in my app using addressbookui framework I am unable to add photo from camera although I can add a photo from photo library. This works as expected in iOS 8 and below versions. I have used even contactsUI API and tried to add a photo from camera but even that doesnot work.

```
//iOS 9
CNContact *contact = [[CNContact alloc] init];
    CNContactViewController *contactVC = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForNewContact:contact];
    [self presentViewController:contactVC animated:YES completion:nil];

//iOS 8
ABNewPersonViewController *unknownPersonViewController = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:unknownPersonViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. If you find any solution to this, please post the same.

Comment: I have files a bug report with apple radar and open radar. http://openradar.appspot.com/22868404

Comment: Tested it on iOS 9.0.2 using an iPhone 6S and the bug is still existent. Camera 'input' just stays black.

Comment: The bug is still open. Dont know when will apple fix this

Comment: I'm experiencing the same, Any update on this ?

Comment: Still exists in iOS 10

Comment: Noticed that 'Take Photo' is not appearing in iOS 11 version, Apple might have removed it as its bug. I did not find an Apple link for official confirmation on this.